# how to configure visual studio 2017 to not generate nuget package as ouput on publish

Tags: visual-studio-2017, publish, nuget-package

This is related to output of publish process in visual studio 2017 (version 15.7.1)
I am developing cross platform application using .net core 2.1. Application will also be compiled on .Net framework 472.
My application requires that output of compilation after publish process should generate dlls and not a nupkg. This is required because my application depend on dynamic loading of the libraries. Since the publish process generates nupkg, I am not able to use output of publish process for dynamically loading of libraries.
I googled the issue but most of the help that I found was on how to generate nuget package whereas my requirement is opposite of that.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this issue by generating output using dotnet publish command over CLI. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore21